# Wordpress - Redirect user to the previous page after successfull login from login page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a wordpress intranet website. You must be logged in to access any pages, otherwise you're redirected to the login page : `mywebsite.com/login`

All the codes I found work if you have a login form in your menu, but not if you have to change the page. Other answers are woocommerce oriented and not suitable.

What I want : The user browses an inacessible page : `mywebsite.com/this-cat/this-page`.
He's redirected to `mywebsite.com/login`. After a successfull login he's redirected to his first request : `mywebsite.com/this-cat/this-page`.

For now, the user is just redirected to the homepage.

I thought that maybe there's a way to filter the redirect, put the slug of the page in a query param, and after the login, filter the redirect to redirect to the slug in query param.

But to be honest, I've no idea which filters to use, ..

Comment: try to add a get param: ?redirect_to=https://url_to_redirect

Comment: THank you, it did the job !

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved my problem, thanks to Stefano's comment. I didn't understand at first what he meant but finally got it.

```php
add_action( 'wp', 'redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page() {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_page('resetpass') && !is_page('lostpassword') && !is_page('login')) {
        global $wp;
        wp_redirect( '/login/?redirect_to='.home_url($wp->request ));
        exit;
    }
}
```

I remembered I was using a function in the code, to redirect the non-logged users. At this moment I understood when and how to save the URL I wanted to redirect.

My biggest concern then, was to know how to properly redirect the user after a successfull login. I tried many codes, but none were working correctly. Then I remembered Stefano's comment, and understood how to proceed. Adding a redirect_to query param in the login URL makes Wordpress redirect you to the URL.

- `$wp->request` returns the path of the page, e.g :
  `/a-category/my-page`
- `home_url()` function helps to build the full URL of this page, e.g :
  `https://my-website.com/a-category/my-page`